# How to make same sized thumbnails

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm having a hard time now trying to make same sized thumbnails, 
I have a simple gallery script that just takes all images out of database and places them to the page with max width 150px and max height 150px.

Now , it looks weird because all images have different shape, is there any way to make them same size without breaking the image apart? The simplest way possible please.
I don't want to have an option on uploading step to chose dimensions for thumbnail.

Comment: Please add some code so we know what you've already tried. It'll make diagnosing the problem a little easier. Also, if you have a staged site up somewhere so we know what "all images have different shape" means.

Comment: well its very simple, the sizes are in the css .. php code is the simplest you've ever seen. `echo '<img class="thumbnail" src="'.$row['img'].'">';`

Comment: when you say the sizes you have are in css did you mean?           img{ height:150px; width:150px;}

Comment: I've had this problem before, unfortunately the <img> tag sucks for this. I've posted an answer below that might work better.

Comment: Are you looking for this ? 
<img src="url" width="150" height="150">

Comment: Annam, EvilNabster is using this css already.  The problem is that the images look distorted due to the changing of its aspect ratio when they are being resized using css.

Answer (score 25):

With `img` you only have two options: Set a maximum width, or a maximum height. Either way you won't get reasonably-sized thumbnails: If you set the maximum width, then some images will be too tall. If you set the maximum height, then some images will be too wide. If you set both width and height, it'll get horribly distorted, because it will ignore the aspect ratio.

Instead, I suggest making a `div` of a fixed size and setting the thumbnail as its `background-image`, then setting `background-size` to `cover`. This will give much better thumbnails, as it scales and crops the image to make it fit. If you want to avoid cutting off the image's edges, give the `div` a `background-color` and set `background-size` to `contain`, which instead scales down the image to make it fit and creates a "letterbox" effect.

Putting it all together (plus thumbnail centring for the crop, and `inline-block` so it acts like an `<img>` tag does):

```
<style>
.thumbnail {
    background-color: black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block; /* makes it fit in like an <img> */
    background-size: cover; /* or contain */
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<div class=thumbnail style="background-image: url(image1.jpg);"></div>
<div class=thumbnail style="background-image: url(image2.jpg);"></div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle demo for `cover`: http://jsfiddle.net/tbeog5o9/24/

And here's a jsfiddle demo for `contain`: http://jsfiddle.net/tbeog5o9/25/

Answer (score 5):

There is another nice way to achieve this using object positioning

```css
.thumbnail video, img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

Please have a look on this [article](https://www.creativebloq.com/css3/control-image-aspect-ratios-css3-2122968) for details

Answer (score 1):

Do all of your images have the same aspect ratio? The aspect ratio is the width divided by the height.

If all images have the same aspect ratio, you can scale them to the same shape by choosing a width and calculating the height, or choosing a height and calculating the width.

If the aspect ratios differ, there is no way to fit the images into the same shape without mangling images. There are two ways to mangle an image:

- Cut off part of the image so that it fits your chosen shape.
- Squeeze or stretch the image into your chosen shape.

If you don't want to mangle your images, you must preserve their aspect ratios. This means, indeed, that the thumbnails will have different shapes. You may think that this looks weird, but most people think it's even weirder when thumbnails are truncated, squeezed, or stretched in order to fit them into a uniform shape.

Comment: "If the aspect ratios differ, there is no way to fit the images into the same shape without mangling images."? This isn't true: You can letterbox or crop.

Comment: My answer uses CSS to do either letter boxing (`contain`) or to crop (`cover`).

Comment: Oh, sorry, you did cover cropping.

Comment: You gave a good answer. I merely wanted to emphasize the impossibility of fitting images into the same "shape" (aspect ratio) without mangling.

Comment: well thats the only option i knew about but i thought somebody would share a jquery option, i know there is some , by setting the percetage of resizement and than showing a part of image only.. ;(

Comment: @EvilNabster Did you look at my answer?

Answer (score -2):

My jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/tbeog5o9/38/

```
<img class="resize" src="http://cdn.moneycrashers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/apple-imac-27.jpg"/>

<img class = "resize" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-pya5LcLCg82HTG3R36aS9B59SSjNzewp8tAHFZrjFjRb1rXI"/>
```

CSS:

```
    img.resize{

    max-width:150px;/*rendered height will be 103px and width will be 150px*/

}
```

You will have to change the img tag url's in my example to match your image url's of course and add the class resize to your img tags.

The rendered height of the image will be 103px but the image will not look distorted.

Comment: The second rule just overwrites the first: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/tbeog5o9/23/